# Vertically align text and box without flexbox

Tags: html, css

So I was forced to work with old technology and got stuck. With flexbox this wouldn't have been an issue, but I can't seem to get it right without it. Here is an example of what I want:

[image]

It's supposed to be straight forward, but being accustomed to flexbox made me a cave animal when it comes to old ways of aligning. Here is what I tried based on suggestions online, but the box and text still aren't aligned vertically. Can someone save me?
(the green border is for better showing if it is centered)

```html
<div style="display: table; height: 30px; overflow: hidden; border:1px solid green;">
<div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
test <span style="display:inline-block; width:30px;height: 30px; margin: 0 5px; border: 1px solid #eee;"></span> test2
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: [https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: middle;` to the `<span>` tag and it shall align.

```html
<div style="display: table; height: 30px; overflow: hidden; border:1px solid green;">
  <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
    test <span style="display:inline-block; width:30px;height: 30px; margin: 0 5px; border: 1px solid #eee;vertical-align: middle;"></span> test2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This. The line-height alternative would be less flexible in terms of dynamic, since this should be the accepted answer :)